# sed -e "s/^[^#][A-Z]/export /g" will remove first letters... how to prevent this matter?

Tags: regex, linux, sed

Say I have this file:

```
#!/bin/bash

#t1.sh
#There are so many comments here
#I HAVE A PEN
VAR=0
#I GOT AN APPLE
mixed
#APPLE PEN HERE
VAR1=$APPLE_PEN
```

Now I want to add "export" before every Variable and print result on the screen. I wrote these variable names in upper case then called this sed command:

```
cat t1.sh|sed -e "s/^[^#][A-Z]/export /g"
```

But the result removed first letters like:

```
#I HAVE A PEN
export R1=0
#I GOT AN APPLE
mixed
#APPLE PEN HERE
export R2=$APPLE_PEN
```

why is that? how to solve it?

---

BTW, 
I could easily make regularexchange on notepad++ on this way:
[image: regularexchange on notepad++]

Will sed also support such exchange too? if so, how to make it?

Comment: You did not use the backreference in sed command. Try `sed -e "s/^\([^#][A-Z]\)/export \1/g"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a capturing group around the pattern and use a backreference in the RHS part to restore that captured text in the result:

```
"s/^\([^#][A-Z]\)/export \1/"
    ^^         ^^        ^^
```

You need to escape the parentheses since you are using the BRE POSIX regex flavor where an unescaped `(` matches a literal open parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^[^#][A-Z]/s/^/export /' file
```

Which would read: If the lines first character is not a hash and the second character is a capital letter then insert `export` followed by a space, at the beginning of the line.

or if you prefer to use a "back reference":

```
sed 's/^[^#][A-Z]/export &/ file
```

N.B. there is no need for the `g` flag on the substitution because when read a line at a time there can only be one start of line.